# Making Microsoft Word track changes tool to show changes only made by one user

Tags: microsoft-word

I've got a fairly large Microsoft Word document that has been modified by six people. All changes (and there are plenty of them) are recorded with track changes tool. I want to see only changes that are made by one certain user. Is it possible (I'm using Microsoft Office 2003)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `Formatting` toolbar click `Show` and then `Reviewers`, from here you can tick/untick each reviewer as you need.

Here's a screenshot I've just created.
Don't have a multi-reviewer file handy so this just shows me:

[image: Menu showing options to hide reviewers]

In Word 2007, the `Reviewers` list has moved to the `Review` tab, `Tracking` box, `Show Markup` dropdown.

Comment: Thanks! I really wonder now how I managed to overlook this menu item...

Comment: its usually the obvious things that people need pointed out to them. Hiding in plain sight and all that.